# usereducer - only persisting certain state to session storage?

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

I have a quiz on verb conjugations. You send filter options on the conjugations you want to the backend, and it sends back the necessary information. In my quiz page, I have a usereducer which will manage all this state. I want the conjugation data as well as the current conjugation (so the current question) index to be persisted to session storage.

However, I don't want data such as the error state, the user input, a should redirect variable (will redirect if the user hasn't specified any filter options) to be persisted because if you refresh a page, you don't expect an error message to persist, or at least I don't feel that's what I want.

The point is, these states can't be separated in different reducers because I want to change some of the local state and the persisted state within the same action.

I came up with a very simple solution, which was to put the state that I want to persist in an object called persisted:

```
{
    persisted: {
       conjugations: [...],
       currentConjugationIndex: 2,
       numOfCorrectAnswers: 1,
       numOfIncorrectAnswers: 3
    },

    userAnswer: "habló",
    error: ""
    ...
}
```

which means that all this state can be within one reducer, and then just persisting that persisted object instead of the whole thing. I just feel like I haven't seen anyone else have this problem, which makes me question whether I should be doing something else. Opinions?

Edit:

my code so far:

```
const useQuizReducer = () => {
    const persistedState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("quiz"));

    const [state, dispatch] = useImmerReducer(
        reducer,
        persistedState 
            ? {...initialStates, persisted: persistedState} 
            : initialStates
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("quiz", JSON.stringify(state.persisted));
    }, [state.persisted])

    const {persisted, ...rest} = state;

    return [{...persisted, ...rest}, dispatch];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are muddling different concerns in your reducer. I recommend you separate them. This usually leads to more clarity in your code and -as a bonus- decreases the chance to have bugs hiding in the thicket of complexity.

- first concern: client side runtime state
- second concern: state persistence between page reloads

You have two different concerns: As a rule of thumb you add two different code sections, one for each concern.
Here is an idea how you could do that:

```
// the reducer only handles your first concern
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, emptyInitialState, tryReadSessionStorage);

// this handles your second concern
useEffect(() => tryUpdateSessionStorage(state), [state]);

// e.g. in some other file
const tryUpdateSessionStorage = ({
  conjugations,
  currentConjugationIndex,
  numOfCorrectAnswers,
  numOfIncorrectAnswers,
}) => {
  try {
    sessionStorage.setItem("quiz", JSON.stringify({
      conjugations,
      currentConjugationIndex,
      numOfCorrectAnswers,
      numOfIncorrectAnswers,
    }));
  } catch (exception) {}
}

const tryReadSessionStorage = (emptyInitialState) => {
  let persistedState;
  try {
    persistedState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("quiz"));
  } catch (exception) {}
  return { ...emptyInitialState, ...persistedState };
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that what I'm already doing?

Comment: Well, that was not clear from the first version of your question. And I still don't see why you need to introduce that artificial `persisted` object. And you might want to make use of the lazy initialization (third param to useReducer) to only check local storage on first render